# YAML syntax error : (Line: 2, Col: 1, Idx: 14) - (Line: 2, Col: 2, Idx: 15): While parsing a block mapping, did not find expected key

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

Been trying to fix this for hours. Im a beginner trying to build a pipeline in Azure Devops for my Automation tests. But while validating the YAML file, I'm getting an error "(Line: 2, Col: 1, Idx: 14) - (Line: 2, Col: 2, Idx: 15): While parsing a block mapping, did not find expected key."

Please refer yaml file below where its showing the error.

```
trigger: none
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: '**\GrizzlyMatters.pjs'
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    vsTestVersion: 'toolsInstaller'

pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
  vmImage: "windows-latest"

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: 2997-lia-functional-tests
      name: 2997-lia-functional-tests
      type: git
      ref: test-integration

#steps:
#  - checkout: self
#  - checkout: 2997-lia-functional-tests
#    clean: true

#Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/releases/download/v1.1.12653/Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe.msixbundle" -OutFile ".\WinGet.msixbundle"
#                 Add-AppxPackage ".\WinGet.msixbundle"

stages:
  - stage: QA
    displayName: QA
    jobs:
      - job: Job1
        displayName: Job1
        continueOnError: true
        pool:
          name: LIA-QAPipeline
          vmImage: "windows-latest"
        steps:
          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: "inline"
              script: |
                C:
                mkdir -p  C:\teams_msi  -Force
                Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://teams.microsoft.com/downloads/desktopurl?env=production&plat=windows&arch=x64&managedInstaller=true&download=true" -OutFile "C:\teams_msi\Teams_windows_x64.msi"
                dir C:\teams_msi\
                msiexec /a C:\teams_msi\Teams_windows_x64.msi /l*v C:\teams_msi\teams_install.log ALLUSERS=1
                mkdir -p C:\QA\testDocs -Force
                dir C:\QA
                $currentuser = $env:UserName
                dir c:\Users\$currentuser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\
          - task: InstallTestCompleteAdapter@1
            inputs:
              installExecutor: true
              updateExecutor: true
              automationToken: "fda25620-974e-4145-a02d-a6054a7ba069"
              logsLevel: "0"
              preferredExecutor: TE
#- task: CmdLine@2
#         ## inputs:
#          #  targetType: 'inline'
#           # script: |
#                  C:
#                  dir
#                  winget -v
#                  winget install Microsoft.Teams --accept-source-agreements
##                  winget list --accept-source-agreements --name Teams
#                 mkdir -p C:\QA\testDocs
#                  cd C:\QA\
#                  dir
```

Comment: Why do you mention two completely different errors in the title and the text? Which one of them happens? And please provide the complete YAML (as text and not as screenshot!) because sometimes those errors can only be seen in the whole context (you can and should overwrite sensitive information like usernames  or repositoriy names)

Comment: Please take a look at David Grayson's answer as well as Vince Bowdren's to see if it is helpful to you. If you think it is a solution, please mark it as a correct answer for others who meet the same question.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax at the beginning of your file looks like it is not valid YAML syntax.  The dash on the second line would imply you are making an element in a list, but you didn't put it inside a list.  By playing around with it at the [YAML Playground](https://eemeli.org/yaml-playground/), I found something similar which might be what you are looking for:

```yaml
trigger: none
task: VSTest@2
inputs:
  testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
  testAssemblyVer2: '**\GrizzlyMatters.pjs'
  searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
  vsTestVersion: 'toolsInstaller'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put your VSTest@2 task there, on line 2. Tasks are only allowed inside the [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/key-pipelines-concepts?view=azure-devops#step) element.

Note: you're getting a *syntax* error because, on a technical level, you have put a list item somewhere where it isn't in a list. But you have a more serious semantic problem; there's no way you could change the syntax to make your pipeline work with that task in that place. You have to move it to inside the stages/jobs/steps.